# How to use class with few img inside as a hover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, hover

I have problem with classes in html/css/a little of jQuery.
[image]

This is what i want to achieve, but after defining class with that hover i can't make it to use on other images, only on that one under which one i wrote it. I hope you can help me figure it out with jQuery. My knowledge is pretty poor for now, sorry.

HTML:

```
   <div id="gallery">
                <img class="image" src="images/image_14.png" >
                <div class="hover_state">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="www.xnxx.com" >
                            <img class="behancew" src="images/image_25.png" >
                            <img class="behanceb"  src="images/image_29.png" >
                        </a>
                        <a href="www.redtube.com" >
                            <img class="fullw" src="images/image_26.png" >
                            <img class="fullb"  src="images/image_27.png" >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="image" src="images/image_18.png" >
                <div class="hover_state">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="#" >
                            <img class="behancew" src="images/image_25.png" >
                            <img class="behanceb"  src="images/image_29.png" >
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" >
                            <img class="fullw" src="images/image_26.png" >
                            <img class="fullb"  src="images/image_27.png" >
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- additional slots
                <img class="image" src="#">
                <img class="image" src="images/image_18.png" >
                <img class="image" src="#"</div>
                <img class="image" src="#">
                    -->
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
    width: 982px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
    width: 452px;
    height: 242px;
    margin: 12px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.hover_state {
    width: 452px;
    height: 242px;
    margin: 12px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    //position: absolute;
    background-color: #20409c;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hover_state:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}


.buttons {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.behancew {
    position:absolute;
    padding: 23px;
}

.behanceb {
    padding: 23px;
}

.behancew:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fullw {
    position:absolute;
    padding: 23px;
}

.fullb {
    padding: 23px;
}

.fullw:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("gallery").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover_state");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover_state");
  }
);
```

Comment: First thing I can see is `$("gallery")` needs to be `$("#gallery")`.

Comment: Also, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve from the jquery code. Is it that when you hover over an image you want the closest 'hover_state' div to show?

Comment: If you do want to find the closest div with class "hover_state" you can use the Jquery .closest() for that http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: spacebean - My goal is to make that "hover_state" hovered for every image in the "#gallery" because for now i can only hover first image and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem here is you want to show each `hover_state` for each `.image`.

Check out this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jN3LX/)**

You may need to wrap the `<img>` and the `hover_state` with another container like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    <div class="hover_state"></div>
</div>
```

And then make a function that show the exact hover_state:

```
$('.item').hover(function(){
    $('.hover_state',this).fadeToggle();
})
```

Comment: Your answer is good! thank you! But can you help me one more time ?

Comment: I deleted comment because when i checked and edited some parts it worked! :) But i want to as you for 1 more thing. Is there an option to not pasting that whole "hover_state" under each image, just to write it one and "somehow" make some magic to make it work for all .image ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k74gG/1/
Here is actual code, i think i miss something or dunno, because on my laptop everything is good, but on fidddle not.

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle in the prev comment ... works with jus one element for all hover states. @Huls

Comment: Okay, now everything is like i wanted, thank you very much man! I would buy you a beer if i could! Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1 more thing (sorry for bothering) but if i would like in a future make other option like:
as you can see on code, each hover on image has "view on behance" and i want on every image to be other href link, how to set up jQuery code to use actual hover_state for each .image, not only 1 for pattern to all ?

Comment: With some data atribute on item you can assign later that value on the behance link and refresh it every time the hover is showed based on the item hovered... maybe you can make another question :)

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote :( but okay, maybe i better make another question... :(